# LibreOffice Writer, Changing orientation only for some pages

Tags: libreoffice

Trying to change the orientation of just one page in LibreOffice I found this help site of libreOffice to [Change the page orientation only for some pages](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Changing_Page_Orientation_Landscape_or_Portrait#To_Change_the_Page_Orientation_Only_for_Some_Pages) but the what it says to taking care of "The Scope of Page Styles" which is at the bottom of help page was not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the relevant information copied from that page.  Be sure to read all three sections, not just the first one, since they go together.

> **The Scope of Page Styles**
>
> You should be aware of the scope of page styles in LibreOffice. Which pages of your text document get affected by editing a page style?
>
> **One Page Long Styles**
>
> A page style can be defined to span one page only. The “First Page” style is an example. You set this property by defining another page style to be the "next style", on the Format - Page - Organizer tab page.
>
> A one page long style starts from the lower border of the current page style range up to the next page break. The next page break appears automatically when the text flows to the next page, which is sometimes called a "soft page break". Alternatively, you can insert a manual page break.
>
> To insert a manual page break at the cursor position, press Ctrl+Enter or choose Insert - Manual Break and just click OK.
>
> **Manually Defined Range of a Page style**
>
> The “Default” page style does not set a different "next style" on the Format - Page - Organizer tab page. Instead, the "next style" is set also to be “Default”. All page styles that are followed by the same page style can span multiple pages. The lower and upper borders of the page style range are defined by "page breaks with style". All the pages between any two "page breaks with style" use the same page style.
>
> You can insert a "page break with style" directly at the cursor position. Alternatively, you can apply the "page break with style" property to a paragraph or to a paragraph style.
>
> Perform any one of the following commands:
>
> - To insert a "page break with style" at the cursor position, choose Insert - Manual Break, select a Style name from the listbox, and click OK.
> - To apply the "page break with style" property to the current paragraph, choose Format - Paragraph - Text Flow. In the Breaks area, activate Enable and With Page Style. Select a page style name from the listbox.
> - To apply the "page break with style" property to the current paragraph style, right-click the current paragraph. Choose Edit Paragraph Style from the context menu. Click the Text Flow tab. In the Breaks area, activate Enable and With Page Style. Select a page style name from the listbox.
> - To apply the "page break with style" property to an arbitrary paragraph style, choose View - Styles and Formatting. Click the Paragraph Styles icon. Right-click the name of the paragraph style you want to modify and choose Modify. Click the Text Flow tab. In the Breaks area, activate Enable and With Page Style. Select a page style name from the listbox.